# Blazorise DataGrid DataGridSelectColumn not recording change

Tags: select, datagrid, blazor-webassembly, blazorise

I am trying to add select in blazorise component. Somehow it not showing me dropdown selected values. Please go through below code

Temp.razor file

```
@page "/temp"
@using Blazorise.DataGrid


<h3>TempComponent</h3>

<DataGrid TItem="ClassA"
              Data="@Classes"
              Editable="true"
              RowUpdated="@OnRowUpdatedAsync">

      <DataGridCommandColumn >
            <EditCommandTemplate>
                <Blazorise.Button Clicked="@context.Clicked"><Icon Name="IconName.Edit" /></Blazorise.Button>
            </EditCommandTemplate>
            <SaveCommandTemplate>
                <Blazorise.Button Clicked="@context.Clicked"><Icon Name="IconName.Save" /></Blazorise.Button>
            </SaveCommandTemplate>
      </DataGridCommandColumn>

      <DataGridColumn TItem="ClassA" Field="@nameof(ClassA.Name)" Caption="Name" Editable="true"/>
      <DataGridSelectColumn TItem="ClassA" Field="@nameof(ClassA.B)" Caption="B" Editable="true">
           <DisplayTemplate>
                  @if (@context.B != null)
                    {
                     @context.B.Name
                    }
            </DisplayTemplate>
            <EditTemplate>             
                     <Select TValue="int" SelectedValue="@selectValue" 
                         SelectedValueChanged="@SelectedValueChangedHandler">
                        @if (ClassesB != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var classB in ClassesB)
                            {
                                <SelectItem  Value="@(classB.Id)">@(classB.Name)</SelectItem>
                            }
                        }
                      </Select>
            
            </EditTemplate>
      </DataGridSelectColumn>
</DataGrid>



@code{
    int selectValue = 0;

    public class ClassA {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ClassB B { get; set;}
    }

    public class ClassB {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    List<ClassA> Classes = new List<ClassA> {
        new ClassA { Name = "Class1", B = new ClassB() { Id = 1, Name = "ClassB1" }},
        new ClassA { Name = "Class2", B = new ClassB() { Id = 2, Name = "ClassB2" }}

    };

    List<ClassB> ClassesB = new List<ClassB> {
        new ClassB { Id = 1, Name = "ClassB1" },
        new ClassB { Id = 2, Name = "ClassB2" }
     };

    protected void OnRowUpdatedAsync(SavedRowItem<ClassA, Dictionary<string, object>> e)
    {
  
    }
    private void SelectedValueChangedHandler(int value)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("values " + value);
        selectValue = value;
    }
}
```

And Current Output Screenshot (**select dropdown value not showing** )
[image]

Whenever user select column then value should be change in list and also display in datagrid.

For this I took reference from https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/561

Please help me to solve this issue .
Thanks in advance